How to make ChromaDB work faster with celery?
I am running jobs in celery that writes to ChromaDB some documents. But it is trying to unpack (as I understand) onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz. It takes too much time to write a single document into Chroma
I want to avoid implementing separate service for working with Chroma. Is there any method to speed up the writing process?
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  56%|#####6    | 44.6M/79.3M [00:27<00:25, 1.43MiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  64%|######3   | 50.7M/79.3M [00:40<00:47, 632kiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  64%|######4   | 50.8M/79.3M [00:40<00:46, 643kiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  56%|#####6    | 44.7M/79.3M [00:27<00:25, 1.43MiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  57%|#####6    | 44.9M/79.3M [00:27<00:24, 1.47MiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  64%|######4   | 50.9M/79.3M [00:40<00:44, 672kiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  57%|#####6    | 45.1M/79.3M [00:27<00:24, 1.45MiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  64%|######4   | 51.0M/79.3M [00:40<00:45, 657kiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  57%|#####7    | 45.3M/79.3M [00:27<00:24, 1.48MiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  64%|######4   | 51.0M/79.3M [00:40<00:44, 673kiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  57%|#####7    | 45.5M/79.3M [00:27<00:24, 1.44MiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  64%|######4   | 51.1M/79.3M [00:40<00:43, 683kiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  58%|#####7    | 45.6M/79.3M [00:27<00:23, 1.51MiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  65%|######4   | 51.2M/79.3M [00:40<00:42, 695kiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  58%|#####7    | 45.8M/79.3M [00:28<00:23, 1.52MiB/s]
/root/.cache/chroma/onnx_models/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/onnx.tar.gz:  65%|######4   | 51.3M/79.3M [00:40<00:42, 697kiB/s]

python = "^3.12"
chromadb = "^0.4.22"
